# make scroll overflow hidden only one page?

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

> I'm making a website using bootstrap, i'm new in bootstrap and j query,there is scrolling problem in a page, so i used overflow hidden in the section of the body, but this is create a new problem , my gallery page not scrolling now, i want to overflow hidden only specific page, when i add a small pic when this scrolling is occur.

**here is html code:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<br />

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12" >
            <img src="~/images/bluetop.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;height:75px" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/slider4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Muneeb Ali" style="width:200px;height:200px"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/xpr2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Muneeb" style="width:200px;height:200px">
                <div class="caption">
                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="~/images/xpr.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Muneeb" style="width:200px;height:200px">
                <div class="caption">
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <img src="~/images/bluebottom.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%;height:auto" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> when i add last class container class this problem occur.

**here is css file:**

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.body-content {
    overflow:hidden;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .nav {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: yes i can, but they said you have not permission

Comment: try this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/sul9bf?p=preview

Comment: how to add pictures?

Comment: can you do, fork--> as public.. and then update that, and then share the link?

Comment: u can upload them here: http://imgur.com/

Answer (score 0):

so I am looking through your code, but you don't seem to have the class "body-content" within the html. To make the select div have a scroll bar you could select it through it's ID/Class, then you would assign "overflow-y: scroll;" or "overflow-z: scroll;". I'd personally say remove that class and apply it to right class.

Comment: the body content class is in master layout

Comment: <div class="container-fluid body-content">
        @RenderBody()

        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Mashad Zaib</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

Comment: Okay, I will leave it here. I thought I could help. I just think he should remove the class.

Comment: anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution.

On the html of the page you want to have the overflow hidden just do :

```
<html style='overflow: hidden !important;'>
</html>
```

And on the css do :

```
html,
body {
 
    overflow: auto;
   
}
```